# How does work varibles with tasks in asyncio?

Tags: python-asyncio

During learning asyncio, I maked misstake, and make link to variable "task1" three times.

```
import asyncio
import time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    print(f"start at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'a'))
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'aba'))
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(3, 'faf'))

    await task1
    #await task2
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

But when I ran code, I got this output

```
start at 19:05:19

a

aba

faf

finished at 19:05:22
```

Why it don't print only last created task?
Why first and second tasks don't cleared?

In clear python, if I write some like this:

```
page = 0
page = 1
page = 2

print(page)
```

I will get "2", because previous links to the objects will removed from the memmory.

Why there it's different? How it works?

Answer (score 0):

You are starting three tasks and waiting for the slowest of the three to complete.

`await task1` is not running the task, it is waiting for the third task object assigned to `task1` to finish. The other two tasks still exist in the event loop and are still running, these finish first because they are faster.

Another way to look at this is to slightly modify your code. This will do what you expect to start with, and then throw errors because the program finishes before the slower tasks.

```
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(3, 'a'))     # make slowest
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'aba'))
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'faf'))   # make fastest
```

Rewriting your code is to remove `task1=` entirely to make it clear that `await task1` has more to do with waiting for the task to finish and little to do with making it run.

```
    asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'a'))
    asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'aba'))
    asyncio.create_task(say_after(3, 'faf'))

    while len(asyncio.all_tasks()) > 1:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    # await task1
```

A more usual way is to collect references to all tasks and await the list of tasks being complete.

```
    tasks = []
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(say_after(3, 'a')))
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'aba')))
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'faf')))

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```